# How to change the color of an element on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css

After moving the mouse, the color in the triangle does not change. how to change it? I'm trying to do it, but I can not do it.

https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/3/

```
<button type="submit">Turn to the dark side</button>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
     text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

button[type=submit] {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color:black;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    color: #ffe200;
    font-size: 22px;
}

button[type=submit]:after {
    content: '';
    border-width: 23px;
    border-color: transparent black black transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 9.5px;
    left: 228px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

button[type=submit]:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffe200;
    border-color: transparent #ffe200 #ffe200 transparent;
}
```

Comment: the border is defined on the after element https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/4/

Comment: Just a friendly tip: dont use css wildcard selectors (`*`). Those are evil and at some point they will devour your soul.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add some `css` lines

```
button[type=submit]:hover:after {
  border-color: #ffe200;
  z-index: -1; // You can change or remove this
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/7/)

Answer (score 0):

See the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/8/

Just added the following line

```
button[type=submit]:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffe200;
}
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your CSS-styling.

```
    button[type=submit]:hover:after {
    border-color: transparent #ffe200 #ffe200 transparent;
}
```